# JavaScript not executing in the on-line version

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to put on-line a test page and everything works as supposed to except the JavaScript doesn't get executed. First i thought it was path issue or errors in the file but now, the file is empty (almost) and the same path is set for a CSS file and that loads in fine.

It's probably something patheticly obvious but i just can't see it. Suggestions on how to shoot it?

The page is [here](http://viltersten.somee.com/TvGuide/TvGuide.aspx). All i need is to get the `alert()` executed on page being loaded ([here](http://viltersten.somee.com/TvGuide/global.js) is the JS-file).

Testing the page locally works perfectly. Submission works on-line as well. It's just the little, evil JS file that doesn't load (or at least doesn't execute).

Comment: it is alerting undefined in chrome, you are not passing anything to one of your alert functions or the variable you are passing has not been assigned.

Comment: what do you exepect, what is the error ?

Comment: Change the alert to `alert("Hi Konrad");` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code in global.js gives me an error in firebug

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert();
});
```

And the error is

```
 Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]
   alert();
```

Comment: WTF?! Why does it work?! I mean, it's great but i only re-published the whole shabang (for, like, fifth time). And even the calender thingy is working! It's like if the server what's to embarrass me, or something. Stupid computer... (And huge thanks. I think i need to start sleeping more...)

Comment: @KonradViltersten more sleep and probably firebug ;)